# Using copyTo formula when automating a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

folks!

I'm getting annoyed after a lot of tries to use the copyTo formula in Google Apps Script. I'm gonna paste below two different situations. The first works perfectly, but it's not the one I need. The second was created by me after understanding how the script works. I don't know why, when I use the method inside an if clause, the formula does not work anymore. Can you help me?

First situation:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("E1:S1").copyTo(sheet.getRange("E35"), {contentsOnly:true})
```

Second situation

```
function copyPasteCFD() {
  var GIVEN_SHEET_NAME = "2 CFD_DB";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();

  if(GIVEN_SHEET_NAME == sheetName) {
    sheet.getRange("E1:S1").copyTo(sheet.getRange("E35"), {contentsOnly:true})
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just check there could be whitespace in your sheet name, maybe something like '2 CFD_DB<space>'

Comment: Hello @AneesHameed. I checked it, but there is no space there. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Before the if statement put the lines `Logger.log("'" + sheetName + "'"); Logger.log("'" + GIVEN_SHEET_NAME + "'"); Logger.log(sheetName == GIVEN_SHEET_NAME)`, run it, then view and post the logs.

Comment: Also, where are you running the script from?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, thanks. I could see that, for some reason, the script was not identifying the space between the number 2 and the letter C. I remove them and now it's working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I'm running on the Google Apps Script "IDE" :)